# How to get logs using rest api in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I went through several guides and couldn't find a way to get the logs with related information like data size of the flowfile(shown in the image) using rest api (or otherway if rest api is not possible).Eventhough nifi writes these logs to app-logs, Other related details can not find from there. How can I do that?[image]

**EDIT**

According to comment from daggett,I have the rest api - http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/flow/bulletin-board, which solved my half of the question. Now I need to know who I can get the flowfile details which caused to the bulletin.

Comment: Use f12 key in browser to see network activity and catch api request to get required log.

Answer (score 1):

There are few controller services provided by nifi which gives in-depth information about status of nifi as well as information about flowfiles. One of those services is  [SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.reporting.SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask/index.html)
 which you can use to derive the information about the failed file.

These controller services basically send information about flowfile as json data which can be queried or processed as flowfile in nifi.

Here is json data that above controller service returns -

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "provenance",
  "namespace" : "provenance",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "eventId", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "eventOrdinal", "type": "long" },
    { "name": "eventType", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "timestampMillis", "type": "long" },
    { "name": "durationMillis", "type": "long" },
    { "name": "lineageStart", "type": { "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis" } },
    { "name": "details", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "componentId", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "componentType", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "componentName", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "processGroupId", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "processGroupName", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "entityId", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "entityType", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "entitySize", "type": ["null", "long"] },
    { "name": "previousEntitySize", "type": ["null", "long"] },
    { "name": "updatedAttributes", "type": { "type": "map", "values": "string" } },
    { "name": "previousAttributes", "type": { "type": "map", "values": "string" } },
    { "name": "actorHostname", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "contentURI", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "previousContentURI", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "parentIds", "type": { "type": "array", "items": "string" } },
    { "name": "childIds", "type": { "type": "array", "items": "string" } },
    { "name": "platform", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "application", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "remoteIdentifier", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "alternateIdentifier", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "transitUri", "type": ["null", "string"] }
  ]
}
```

`entityId` ,`entitySize` is what you may be looking for.